# Matlab : expandable array, lost data

Tags: arrays, matlab, expandable

I have two columns of data. First column is time and second column is a function of time. However some time values are lost, so the function values. I don't know the index of the lost row (the amount of data is too large). For example, I have this:

```
 t   x+w
2t  2x+w
3t  3x+w
6t  6x+w
7t  7x+w
```

However, it should be like:

```
 t   x+w
2t  2x+w
3t  3x+w
4t  4x
5t  5x
6t  6x+w
7t  7x+w
```

I want to expand the time array and add the corresponding function values. Actually f(t) is random but have a linear growing deterministic behaviour. Thus, It does not matter if I add two values among the thousands. So how can I do this in Matlab?

Sorry for my English. I hope I could explain myself.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data looks like this:

```
t = [1 2 3 6 7];
x = 2;
w = 10;
X = t*x + w;
```

now you can just [interpolate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to get the missing X values:

```
ti = 1:7;
Xi = interp1(t, X, ti);
```

or if you're saying you have this:

```
t = [1 2 3 6 7];
X = rand(size(t));
```

then to fill in random values:

```
Xi(t) = X; %Space out the origianl random value according to t
Xi(setdiff(1:7,t)) = rand() %Find the missing vlaues using setdiff and replace them with new random values
ti = 1:7;
```

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO. If it is correct, please mark it so by clicking on the tick in the top right hand corner of the answer.